# organize activities in a folder

Tags: android-activity, android-manifest

Hi I'm building my first android app, i like to have separate files for each class in my Android projects.
now i have:

```
src-->com-->quickorder-->activities 
(in this folder i want to put all my activity files)

src-->com-->quickorder-->activities-->MainActivity.java
src-->com-->quickorder-->activities-->DbSincroActivity.java
```

manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.quickorder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

 <activity
    android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <activity android:name=".activity.DbSincroActivity"></activity>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.quickorder;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
....
....
}
```

is this a correct statement?

Answer (score 2):

No, you have

```
android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
```

you need to refer to the activities sub-root such as

```
android name=".activities.MainActivity"
```

Manifest takes that dot to mean that it's a subfolder of your package that you declared.